# Brown spots on bell pepper

Tags: bell-peppers

I noticed these brown spots appearing on my bell pepper yesterday. I live in Texas so it is very hot (I think it’s sun scorching) but I have had an incident where ants ate my tomato! I hand water once or twice a day depending on how hot it is outside. Let me know what you think [image]

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, in this case, as it looks a little bit iffy, but it looks like either blossom end rot (BER) or sunscald (probably the former). It could potentially keep showing up as long as it's hot, and clear up afterward. Nutrients might help, but don't count on it 100%.

BER is caused by calcium not getting to where it needs to go. There are a lot of reasons this could be the case:

- Calcium-deficiency (Don't assume this is the problem; too much calcium can raise your soil pH and cause issues)
- Nutrient imbalance (such as not enough nitrogen and too much calcium, or vice versa, among other possibilities)
- Hot, dry weather (temperature changes what nutrients in the soil are most/least available)
- A problem with the way you're watering (water also changes what nutrients are most/least available).
- It may be that your soil needed more organic matter, mulch, or something like that.
- A soil pH imbalance
- Diseases (they can interrupt nutrient flow)